# passing arguments to funcyion in dll C++

Tags: c++, function, dll, integer, parameter-passing

Im getting garbage value in function in dll.

in FUNC1(int) im getting garbage value, any help??

.h of dll

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Class1
    {
    public:
          bool __stdcall FUNC1(int);
}
```

FUNC1 definition

```
bool Class1::FUNC1(int i)
{
//here im getting i as some garbage value
   (500==i) ? return true: return false;
}
```

this is how im calling FUNC1

```
FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = GetProcAddress(HMODULE (hGetProcIDDLL),FUNC1); 
        if(lpfnGetProcessID == NULL) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        typedef int (__stdcall * pICFUNC)(int);
        pICFUNC dllFunc;
        dllFunc = pICFUNC(lpfnGetProcessID); 

        int op = dllFunc(500);
```

Comment: You don't do error checking that you have a valid function pointer.

Comment: edited FUNC1 declaration

Answer (score 0):

FUNC1 is declared as a function, but the definition is a method of "Class". Since they don't match, the implementation will expect to have a this pointer and a parameter on the stack. The caller is only pushing the i parameter, the implementation will be looking for it at the incorrect memory location.

Comment: I fave def file for dll which contains  FUNC1

Comment: Even in that case, pICFUNC is a pointer to a function with the prototype "int __stdcall func(int x)". What you need is a pointer to a member function of a class; that would be "typedef int __stdcall (Class::*pICFUNC)(int)". Invocation of this pointer now gets interesting: "(obj.*pICFUNC)(500)".